# Titanium IOS Picker Example

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am almost new on titanium and iOS development.
I want to know how to use `Picker` with `DONE` and `CANCEL` buttons selected data show in textfield.
Is there any example?
Thank you

Comment: What have you done so far? Have you read related documentations and tutorials?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020915/titanium-mobile-date-picker-from-text-field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go Following code would help you make what you want using titanium

http://cssgallery.info/making-a-combo-box-in-titanium-appcelerator-code-and-video/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead try this,ay little help you.

```
http://nscookbook.com/2013/01/ios-programming-recipe-7-using-the-uipickerview/
```

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPickerView_Example
http://www.developersalmanac.com/uipickerview-tutorial/